# MuPdf save file after annotation android

Tags: java, android, mupdf

I am using mupdf library for annotation. after annotation when we backpress on mupdfactivity below code is written

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (core != null && core.hasChanges()) {
        DialogInterface.OnClickListener listener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                if (which == AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE)
                    core.save();

                finish();
            }
        };
        AlertDialog alert = mAlertBuilder.create();
        alert.setTitle("Save Changes");
        alert.setMessage(getString(R.string.document_has_changes_save_them_));
        alert.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE,
                getString(R.string.yes), listener);
        alert.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE,
                getString(R.string.no), listener);
        alert.show();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

But when I click on core.save() method it redirects me to native function body in MuPdfCore.java.

```
private native void saveInternal();
```

I want to change the path for saving file. Searching for this method implementation, where can I get the implementation of save method? If anyone has worked on this?

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 1):

You can find the function you are looking and all other native functions that are called form the Java side in `platform/android/jni/mupdf.c`.

You can modify this function to accept a new path by changing its declaration to

```
JNI_FN(MuPDFCore_saveAsInternal)(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz, jstring jpath)
```

The function can then be made accessible to the Java side via a declaration like

```
private native int saveAsInternal(String path);
```

in the class `MuPDFCore`.

In the C code you can get the path that was passed as a Java string via something like

```
const char *new_path = NULL;                                                            
if (jpath != NULL) {
    public static native boolean javascriptSupported();
    new_path = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, jpath, NULL);
}
```

Hope that helps.